# salesforce soql campaigns with influenced opportunities

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm trying to create a SOQL query that returns a list of **Campaigns with Influenced Opportunties**, similar to the standard campaign report with the same name.  The following doesn't seem to be returning the same values as the report:

```
SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunity
where CampaignId in (SELECT CampaignId from CampaignMember where CampaignId = '??')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're after something simple - this might be enough:

```
SELECT Campaign.Name, Id, Name, Amount
FROM Opportunity
WHERE CampaignId != null AND CloseDate = THIS_MONTH
```

You can easily convert it to an aggregated query that'd give you totals per campaign too:

```
SELECT Campaign.Name, Campaign.NumberOfOpportunities, SUM(Amount), COUNT(Id)
FROM Opportunity
WHERE CampaignId != null AND CloseDate = THIS_MONTH
GROUP BY Campaign.Name, Campaign.NumberOfOpportunities
```

(if you'll get a discrepancy between `Campaign.NumberOfOpportunities` and count of Opps it's OK. It's because the first field is an "all time counter" and the later one is impacted by the `WHERE CloseDate = THIS_MONTH`)

---

If you need whole set of data exactly as returned by the report (especially the "Responded") it's going to be tricky because the [ERD diagram for these objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm) is a bit nasty.

> Campaign Influence allows marketers to measure and report on multiple
>   campaigns that have influenced a single opportunity.

So we could somehow start from Contact, go to Opportunities via OpportunityContactRole. And in same time from Contact go to CampaignMembers to Campaign.

```
SELECT Name, Email, Account.Name, 
    (SELECT HasResponded, Campaign.Name FROM CampaignMembers),
    (SELECT Opportunity.Name, Opportunity.Amount FROM OpportunityContactRoles)
FROM Contact 
LIMIT 10
```

You'd however have to process the results of the query to obtain the campaign names (and I don't think subqueries are allowed to be exported with Data Loader for example).

---

Last but not least - if you are interested in **only one Campaign or only one Opp** it can be simplified (and you were quite close!)

```
SELECT Contact.Name, Opportunity.Account.Name, Opportunity.Name, Opportunity.Amount
FROM OpportunityContactRole
WHERE ContactId IN (SELECT ContactId FROM CampaignMember WHERE Campaign.Name = 'Sample Campaign')
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and detailed response.  This has been extremely helpful.

Comment: Your last example is the closest to what i'm looking for but I'm stuck because it's returning a list of all the Opportunities for the Contact, not just the opportunity tied to the Campaign in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Add `... AND Opportunity.Campaign.Name = 'Sample Campaign'` at the end then?

Comment: Thanks, once again.  I tried that but the opportunity is not showing now at all now.  When I query an Opportunity object which shows up on the report, I see that the CampaignId field is empty.  So before adding the AND clause I can see all the opportunities for the Contact but I don't know how to limit the query to return the the Campaign that I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm afraid there's only so much we can try :/ These reports are special, there must be some simpler relationship table that they don't expose to us (influence counts only before Opp is closed but all my queries will give you false positives if you'll add contact roles to the Opp after it was closed)... You could fine tune this with Apex-based filtering or examine the "field history" on objects to handcraft exact results... But that's over the scope of 1 simple query. You can always try asking support for assistance? ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've tried SF support but was directed to post on the developer forums. There were some campaign influence questions posted there but they didn't help much.  I'll post back if/when I get this working.